# SyncFusion BoldReports ReportViewer The data source has both or neither of the following: DataSourceReference and ConnectionProperties

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, rdlc, syncfusion

I am using SyncFusion BoldReports ReportViewer and getting the following error:

The data source has both or neither of the following: DataSourceReference and ConnectionProperties. The data source must have exactly one of these elements.

We have an angular 6 based site with remote WebAPI. What we are trying to do is load the report data when it gets to the ReportAPIController

printexposure.component.html: This part seems solid, as it is calling the report and trying to process it.

```
  <bold-reportviewer id="viewer" 
  [reportServiceUrl] = "serviceUrl" 
  [reportPath]="PrintExpo.rdlc"
  [processingMode] = "Local"
  (ajaxBeforeLoad) = "onAjaxRequest($event)"
  style="width: 100%;height: 600px">
  </bold-reportviewer>
```

On the controller side:

```
  public class ReportApiController : ApiController, IReportController, IReportLogger
  {
    Dictionary<string, object> jsonArray = null;
    string parameterJsonData = null;

    //Post action for processing the rdl/rdlc report 
    public object PostReportAction([FromBody]Dictionary<string, object> jsonResult)
    {
      jsonArray = jsonResult;
      if (jsonArray.ContainsKey("customData"))
      {
        //Get client side JSON custom data, desirialize it
        parameterJsonData = jsonArray["customData"].ToString();
      }
      return ReportHelper.ProcessReport(jsonResult, this);
    }

    //Get action for getting resources from the report
    [System.Web.Http.ActionName("GetResource")]
    [System.Web.Mvc.AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public object GetResource(string key, string resourcetype, bool isPrint)
    {
      return ReportHelper.GetResource(key, resourcetype, isPrint);
    }

    //Method will be called when initialize the report options before start processing the report        
    public void OnInitReportOptions(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
    {
      reportOption.ReportModel.ReportPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/ReportAssets/" + reportOption.ReportModel.ReportPath);

      var paramList = JObject.Parse(parameterJsonData);

      int userId = Int32.Parse(paramList["userId"].ToString());
      int centreId = Int32.Parse(paramList["centerId"].ToString());

      reportOption.ReportModel.DataSources.AddRange(Helpers.ReportDataHelper.getReportDataSources(userId, centreId, parameterJsonData));
    }

    //Method will be called when reported is loaded
    public void OnReportLoaded(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
    {
      var reportParameters = ReportHelper.GetParameters(jsonArray, this);
      var paramList = JObject.Parse(parameterJsonData);

      List<BoldReports.Web.ReportParameter> setParameters = new List<BoldReports.Web.ReportParameter>();
      if (reportParameters != null)
      {
        foreach (var rptParameter in reportParameters)
        {
          var paramValue = paramList[rptParameter.Name].ToString();

          setParameters.Add(new BoldReports.Web.ReportParameter()
          {
            Name = rptParameter.Name,
            Values = new List<string>() { paramValue }
          });
        }
        reportOption.ReportModel.Parameters = setParameters;
      }
    }

    public void LogError(string message, Exception exception, MethodBase methodType, ErrorType errorType)
    {
      WriteLogs(string.Format("Error Message: {0} \n Stack Trace: {1}", message, exception.StackTrace));
    }

    public void LogError(string errorCode, string message, Exception exception, string errorDetail, string methodName, string className)
    {
      WriteLogs(string.Format("Class Name: {0} \n Method Name: {1} \n Error Message: {2} \n Stack Trace: {3}", className, methodName, errorDetail, (exception == null ? "no exception" : exception.StackTrace)));
    }

    internal void WriteLogs(string errorMessage)
    {
      // Error details text file path location
      string filePath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/App_Data/Errordetails.txt");
      using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(filePath, true))
      {
        writer.AutoFlush = true;
        writer.WriteLine(errorMessage);
      }
    }
  }
```

This is where it throws the error.

My helper class on the API side that retrieves the data:

```
  public static class ReportDataHelper
  {
    public static List<BoldReports.Web.ReportDataSource> getReportDataSources(int userId, int centreId, string parameterJsonData)
    {
      var paramList = JObject.Parse(parameterJsonData);
      string ReportName = paramList["ReportName"].ToString();
      
      switch (ReportName.ToLower())
      {
        case "expo":
          return getExpoPrintDataSources(userId, centreId, parameterJsonData);
          break;
        case "":
          break;
      }

      return null;
    }
    private class CaseReportParameters
    {
      public string ReportName { get; set; }
      public int CaseId { get; set; }
      public bool allowPrintPHI { get; set; }
      public bool allowPrintReviews { get; set; }
      public int userId { get; set; }
      public int centerId { get; set; }
    }

    private static List<BoldReports.Web.ReportDataSource> getExpoPrintDataSources(int userId, int centreId, string parameterJsonData)
    {
      //Get client side JSON custom data, desirialize it and store in local variable.
      var expoParams = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CaseReportParameters>(parameterJsonData);

      bool EditMode = false;

      var exposureDetails = new ExposureBL().GetExposureDetails(expoParams.CaseId, userId, centreId, EditMode, expoParams.allowPrintPHI);

      // flatten out lab tests and responses
      var LabTestList = new List<LabTest>();
      foreach (var lab in exposureDetails.LabList)
      {
        if (lab.LabTestList.Count > 0)
        {
          LabTestList.AddRange(new List<LabTest>(lab.LabTestList));
        }
      }
      var ResponseList = new List<Response>();
      foreach (var review in exposureDetails.ReviewList)
      {
        if (review.ResponseList.Count > 0)
        {
          ResponseList.AddRange(new List<Response>(review.ResponseList));
        }
      }
      var r = new List<BoldReports.Web.ReportDataSource>();

      var ExpoDataSet = exposureDetails;
      r.Add(new BoldReports.Web.ReportDataSource("CallInfo", exposureDetails.CallInfo));
      return r;
    }
  }
```

Here is the xml in my printexpo.rdlc, when I created this it was in Project.Services.DTO.DTO so I could get the schema for the data class "CallInfo", then I shifted it into the Project.Services.WebAPI. I figured it shouldn't be an issue as the report file and dataset in it is just a schema and I am loading the data via the API above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Report xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/reporting/2008/01/reportdefinition" xmlns:rd="http://schemas.microsoft.com/SQLServer/reporting/reportdesigner">
  <Body>
    <ReportItems>
      <Textbox Name="Textbox1">
        <CanGrow>true</CanGrow>
        <KeepTogether>true</KeepTogether>
        <Paragraphs>
          <Paragraph>
            <TextRuns>
              <TextRun>
                <Value>Exposure Report by HF</Value>
                <Style />
              </TextRun>
            </TextRuns>
            <Style />
          </Paragraph>
        </Paragraphs>
        <rd:DefaultName>Textbox1</rd:DefaultName>
        <Top>0.45917in</Top>
        <Left>0.61333in</Left>
        <Height>0.3in</Height>
        <Width>2.93333in</Width>
        <Style>
          <Border>
            <Style>None</Style>
          </Border>
          <PaddingLeft>2pt</PaddingLeft>
          <PaddingRight>2pt</PaddingRight>
          <PaddingTop>2pt</PaddingTop>
          <PaddingBottom>2pt</PaddingBottom>
        </Style>
      </Textbox>
    </ReportItems>
    <Height>2in</Height>
    <Style />
  </Body>
  <Width>6.5in</Width>
  <Page>
    <LeftMargin>1in</LeftMargin>
    <RightMargin>1in</RightMargin>
    <TopMargin>1in</TopMargin>
    <BottomMargin>1in</BottomMargin>
    <Style />
  </Page>
  <AutoRefresh>0</AutoRefresh>
  <DataSources>
    <DataSource Name="ProjectServicesDTODTO">
      <ConnectionProperties>
        <DataProvider>System.Data.DataSet</DataProvider>
        <ConnectString>/* Local Connection */</ConnectString>
      </ConnectionProperties>
      <rd:DataSourceID>f4886133-224b-4299-ac3a-3e75b921c3f4</rd:DataSourceID>
    </DataSource>
  </DataSources>
  <DataSets>
    <DataSet Name="CallInfo">
      <Query>
        <DataSourceName>ProjectServicesDTODTO</DataSourceName>
        <CommandText>/* Local Query */</CommandText>
      </Query>
      <Fields>
        <Field Name="CallDateTime">
          <DataField>CallDateTime</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.DateTimeOffset, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallEmployeeId">
          <DataField>CallEmployeeId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallEmployeeName">
          <DataField>CallEmployeeName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerCityName">
          <DataField>CallerCityName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerCountryId">
          <DataField>CallerCountryId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerCountryName">
          <DataField>CallerCountryName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerEmail">
          <DataField>CallerEmail</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerFirstName">
          <DataField>CallerFirstName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerLastName">
          <DataField>CallerLastName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerPhoneNotes">
          <DataField>CallerPhoneNotes</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerPostCode">
          <DataField>CallerPostCode</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerPrimaryAddress">
          <DataField>CallerPrimaryAddress</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerPrimaryPhone">
          <DataField>CallerPrimaryPhone</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerSecondaryAddress">
          <DataField>CallerSecondaryAddress</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerSecondaryPhone">
          <DataField>CallerSecondaryPhone</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerSiteId">
          <DataField>CallerSiteId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerSiteName">
          <DataField>CallerSiteName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerStateId">
          <DataField>CallerStateId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerStateName">
          <DataField>CallerStateName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerTitleId">
          <DataField>CallerTitleId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallerTitleName">
          <DataField>CallerTitleName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallId">
          <DataField>CallId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallLockUserId">
          <DataField>CallLockUserId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CallLockUserName">
          <DataField>CallLockUserName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CaseNumber">
          <DataField>CaseNumber</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CentreId">
          <DataField>CentreId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CentreInitial">
          <DataField>CentreInitial</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="CentreName">
          <DataField>CentreName</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.String</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="IsCallLock">
          <DataField>IsCallLock</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Boolean, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="TempCallId">
          <DataField>TempCallId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Nullable`1[[System.Int32, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
        <Field Name="UserId">
          <DataField>UserId</DataField>
          <rd:TypeName>System.Int32</rd:TypeName>
        </Field>
      </Fields>
      <rd:DataSetInfo>
        <rd:DataSetName>Project.Services.DTO.DTO</rd:DataSetName>
        <rd:TableName>CallInfo</rd:TableName>
        <rd:ObjectDataSourceType>Project.Services.DTO.DTO.CallInfo, Project.Services.DTO, Version=0.9.209.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null</rd:ObjectDataSourceType>
      </rd:DataSetInfo>
    </DataSet>
  </DataSets>
  <rd:ReportUnitType>Inch</rd:ReportUnitType>
  <rd:ReportID>8977239d-4165-47c5-94b3-9a7a807bf8e3</rd:ReportID>
</Report>
```

I've only found one similar issue with SyncFusion: https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/162953/the-data-source-x-has-both-or-neither-of-the-following-datasourcereference-and where they tell the chap to include an extension for BoldReport in the project, which I have done also with no avail. Not sure what it was supposed to do lol.

The report above is simpified there's a lot more to go in it and I am quite stuck any help would be greatly appreciated.

I am novice when it comes to report designs, is it possible to remove/ignore datasources? As I am loading the datasets myself in the ReportApiController?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set a report viewer processing mode as Local in your client side application. For processing mode property value you have to bind in typescript file. Could you please use the below code snippet in your application.

app.component.html  file

```
<bold-reportviewer id="viewer"  
  [reportServiceUrl] = "serviceUrl"  
  [reportPath]="reportPath" 
  [processingMode] = "Local" 
  (ajaxBeforeLoad) = "onAjaxRequest($event)" 
  style="width: 100%;height: 600px"> 
  </bold-reportviewer>
```

app.component.ts file

```
  export class AppComponent { 
  public serviceUrl: string; 
  public reportPath:string; 
  public Local:string; 

    constructor() { 
     this.reportPath = 'PrintExpo.rdlc' 
     this.Local="Local" 
    } 
}
```